# Reflowing comment blocks with vim

Tags: vim, editor, comments, reflow

I'm cleaning up someone else's code and working with vim.  I'd like to reflow the comments so that they're formatted consistently.

For example:

```
    # one two three four five six seven
    # eight nine
    # ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen
    # fifteen sixteen seventeen 
    # eighteen
    # nineteen
```

Would become:

```
    # one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
    # twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen
    # eighteen nineteen
```

So, a workflow that would easily uncomment the code, reflow the paragraph and then re-comment the code with the indentation preserved.  If there is an existing plugin which does exactly this, that would be great.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The `gq` command takes comments and indentation into account. I normally use <kbd>V</kbd> to visually select the lines (with <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>j</kbd>) and then press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>. The `textwidth` option is used to format the lines at the appropriate length. See `:help gq` for more information.

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  I had tried this before, but it didn't work for me.  I just tried it in a fresh account without a .vimrc and it works perfectly.  I guess I'll figure out where my defaults are getting in the way.

Comment: So, it turns out there was a ":set paste" in my .vimrc that was messing with the formatting.  Mystery solved and I can happily reflow my comments.  :)

Comment: Also ensure you have formatoptions set to include t, c, and q. I just spent an hour trying to figure out why this wasn't working because my formatoptions were set to l only.

Comment: I like the sequence '{gq}' This will reflow the current paragraph ({ and } navigate to beginning and end of current para, respectively)

Comment: Is `q` short for something? Or does anyone have a mnemonic for remembering it?

Comment: @reedstrm: You can also use 'gqip' for the same effect. 'ip' stands for 'inner paragraph'.

Comment: @Xiao i've only ever seen the docs refer to it as the `q` command. suggestions: `quintessential` as in make the selection perfectly representative of well formatted content. `qt` like `cutie` from `prettify`. `quotable` as in put the content into a form that is quotable to or shareable with others. `qualify` as in to make fit for (the) special purpose (of being readable, maintainable code); or, as in to make less harsh or strict--in the sense of the degree of style quirks you subject others to, rather than syntax conformity). `quillwork` as in the ornamental work of text reflow.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in command text reflow:

```
gwip - reflow paragraph
```

So when you have this:

```
# one two three four five six seven
# eight nine
# ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen
# fifteen sixteen seventeen 
# eighteen
# nineteen
```

It becomes this:

```
# one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen
# fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen
```

It will also break long lines into smaller ones.

Comment: Neat. This is pretty similar to `gqip` as suggested in one of the comments on the original answer, but it looks like this one keeps the cursor in the original position afterwards.